# Centering text in the middle of the div with height set to 100%

Tags: html, css

I have structure:

```css
    .itemWrapper{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 20%;
    }
    .itemNumber{
        position: relative;
        float:left;
        height: 100%;
        width: 20%;
    }
    .itemName{
        height: 100%;
        width: 20%;
        position: relative;
        float:left
    }
```

```html
    <div class = "itemWrapper">
       <div class = "itemNumber">2</div>
       <div class = "itemName"> name </div<
    </div>
```

I need to center the text inside `.itemNumber` and `.itemName` vertically, how can I do that? I know about `line-height` trick, however the height of the container is in %, what is the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Add display flex and align items:

```
.itemNumber, .itemName {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: but usin this, i wont be able to horizontally align the text, or am i wrong?

Comment: Just add `justify-content: center;`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Flex:

```
.itemWrapper{
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    background-color: silver;
}
.itemNumber{
    width: 20%;
    align-self: center;
}
.itemName{
   width: 20%;
   align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: This will lose the height of text wrapper elements.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css code

```
.itemNumber, .itemName {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center
 }
```